# Updating div from textarea value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a thing kind of like the Tryit Editor of W3schools, but it's not working. I've done pretty much the exact same thing as a jsfiddle, but it doesn't work.

Here's the Javascript function.

```
function update(){
            var value = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
            var change = document.getElementById('change');
            change.innerHTML = value;
        }
```

[Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XHVL2/1/)

Super confused here. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: says update is not defined. and textarea has a class named textinput, not id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea class="textinput" rows=10 cols=50></textarea>
```

should be:

```
<textarea id="textinput" rows=10 cols=50></textarea>
```

If your experimenting with this in JSFiddle, it won't work unless you change **onDomready** to **No wrap - in `<head>`** in Frameworks & Extensions tab.

Comment: fixed my problem nonetheless, thank you! Setting this as the correct answer ASAP

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of the inline `onClick` event, so I moved it to the JS:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    var value = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
    var change = document.getElementById('change');
    change.innerHTML = value;
}
```

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/XHVL2/6/)

Edit: Turns out the inline `onClick` just wasn't working for me until I changed the setting to `No wrap - in <body>`.

Your HTML also had some errors in it, such as referencing the `textarea` by its `id`, but instead you gave it a `class`

Comment: They don't wanna listen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ok, I had some fun, wondered what could go wrong.

You had

```
getElementByID()
```

connected to a `class`.

And in order to make it in JSFIDDLE work I had to put an

```
window.update = update;
```

into the code.

But go with @Charlie's code of separating that!!
:)

**JSFIDDLE:**http://jsfiddle.net/XHVL2/4/

Answer (score 0):

I like more a *live editor* than having to click *W3sc````s-alike* buttons...

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XHVL2/9/)

```
 <body>
        <div id="content">
            <header>
                <h1 class="maintitle">TEST HTML/CSS CODE</h1>
            </header>
            <h1>Input:</h1>
            <textarea id="textinput" rows=10 cols=50></textarea>
            <h1>Output:</h1>
            <div id="result" style="border:2px solid #ccc;">(No HTML)</div>
        </div>
</body>
```

```
var doc = document;
function el(id){
    return doc.querySelector(id);
}
function applyResult(){
    el("#result").innerHTML = this.value;
}

el("#textinput").addEventListener('keyup', applyResult, false);
```

or to provide a much simpler way to handle events like: *keyup, paste, change, propertychange* etc...
**using jQuery:**

[**jQuery LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XHVL2/13/)

```
var $res = $('#result'),
    $inp = $('#textinput');
$inp.on('input', function(){ $res.html( this.value ); });
```

Comment: Haha, yeah, explaining to him, that "copying a value to another box" makes it *not* W3SCHOOL is far behind this thread, I guess. ;)

Comment: To make a live preview all I did was add this to the HTML tag:
onkeyup="update()"

Answer (score 0):

Your `textinput` should be an `id`, not a `class` since you are using the `getElementById`:

```
<textarea id="textinput" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

And to be able to run it is JSFiddle, set `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>` in the Frameworks & Extensions panel on the upper left.